# Optimize correlated update

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlperformance

How do I improve performance of the following query:

```
update t 
set t.recent_5_min = (select MIN(value) 
                      from t t2 
                      where t2.date between t.date - 5 and t.date - 1)
```

`t` has:

- recent_5_min - money null - **of course it's nullable, as it only gets poluplated by a job.**
- value - money non-null
- date - int, PK with clustered index on it. This is the only index on the table.

`t` has 900K records, stats are up to date, the query takes forever to run.

**Update 1** - Sample data generated by the query I posted initially.

**Before:**

```
date        value                 recent_5_min
----------- --------------------- ---------------------
1           10.00                 NULL
2           19.00                 NULL
3           2.00                  NULL
4           9.00                  NULL
5           11.00                 NULL
```

**After:**

```
date        value                 recent_5_min
----------- --------------------- ---------------------
1           10.00                 NULL
2           19.00                 10.00
3           2.00                  10.00
4           9.00                  2.00
5           11.00                 2.00
```

Comment: You are using a correlated subquery here. It performs `min` for each record in `t`. It appears that you can't easily transpose it to uncorrelated version.

Comment: If you convert the query to `select` and find out that it runs in acceptable amount of time then the problematic part is update itself. If there are triggers on `t` table investigate them first and disable them if this change of data does not concern them. Otherwise try to break updates into batches of approximately 10000 rows. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244360/how-to-update-2-new-columns-created-in-a-table-which-has-more-than-250-million-r/17244402#17244402) for details.

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović you are right and I like long names

Comment: The subquery takes the minimal `value` from the *previous* 5 days. But if there's no data in the previous 5 days for a certain date, the subquery will return NULL and your UPDATE will attempt to store the NULL into the non-nullable `recent_5_min` column (and fail).

Comment: You could clear this up a bit with some sample data before the update and how it's supposed to look after the update.

Comment: @Andriy M Totally beside the point, but you are right. The column is nullable apologies.

Comment: And are you performing this update *once* or are you going to have to perform it over and over again every time the data changes? Why not just calculate it at runtime - when you run the query - for the actual date range you are interested in, instead of updating the entire table?

Comment: @user1514042: Yes, I was simply trying to make sure I understood the logic and that inconsistency kind of impeded my understanding. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand it's a repeating process alright, I only get access to the table when the data is already there.

Comment: So when you repeat the process, do you really need to update all the way back to row 2? Has any of that older data changed? And again, why update the table at all if you can calculate this at query time for the subset of data you're interested in?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand I want it to be just and update with no 'has-a-chance-to-changed' checks, as that data we get can cover up totally random ranges of date values, I see where you coming from though. We always get the whole t overwritten, which null recent_5_min values, which is beyond our control.

Comment: I still don't understand. How is row 2 every going to change, once you've calculated it once? And if it *can* change, what is the point of storing the calculation?

Comment: The sql is part of the workflow, once the data is arrived (with and unpredictable date range) I've to run that query and send the results further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
    update t 
    set t.recent_5_min = tmin.minvalue 
    from t 
    join (
            select t1.date, min(t2.value) as minvalue
            from t t1 
            join t t2 
              on t2.date between t1.date - 5 and t1.date - 1 
            group by t1.date
         ) tmin 
      on t.date = tmin.date
   where t.recent_5_min is null or t.recent_5_min <> tmin.minvalue
```

If date is a PK this might work
NOT tested and a good chance it won't work

```
update t1
set t1.recent_5_min = min(t2.value) 
from t t1 
join t t2 
  on t2.date between t1.date - 5 and t1.date - 1 
where t1.recent_5_min is null or t1.recent_5_min <> min(t2.value)
group by t1.date
```

Comment: the first query run within an acceptable period of time, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that subquery is executed for each row. At the same time query not seem as heavy for 900K records.

---

**Added:**

After some experiments I found following. Interesting that query plans for

```
update top (100) t
set t.recent_5_min = (select MIN(value) 
                      from t t2 
                      where t2.date between t.date - 5 and t.date - 1)
from t t
```

and

```
update top (500) t
set t.recent_5_min = (select MIN(value) 
                      from t t2 
                      where t2.date between t.date - 5 and t.date - 1)
from t t
```

are noticeably different. In the second case (and seems in original query also) Sort operator appears in the query plan performing sort over the `value` taking enormous resources.

I tried following manual pivot/unpivot/aggregate technique, that transform query causing Constant Scan operator to be used instead of Sort, which is way better in this case:

```
;with cte as (
    select t.date, t.recent_5_min, m.minVal
    from t
        left join t t1 on t1.date = t.date - 1
        left join t t2 on t2.date = t.date - 2
        left join t t3 on t3.date = t.date - 3
        left join t t4 on t4.date = t.date - 4
        left join t t5 on t5.date = t.date - 5
        cross apply (select min(val) from (values (t1.value), (t2.value), (t3.value), (t4.value), (t5.value)) f(val)) m(minVal)
)
update cte set recent_5_min = minVal
```

For me it passed just for a few seconds for generated 900K rows.

The following work also, but takes longer time and more reads:

```
declare @t int
select @t = 100
update top (@t) percent t 
set t.recent_5_min = (select MIN(value) 
                      from t t2 
                      where t2.date between t.date - 5 and t.date - 1)
from t t
```

For `t2.date between t.date - 240 and t.date - 1` it took about a minute for me.

Comment: it is indeed, it basically executes between for each row, but given that betweens on clustered index should be quite fast I dont' understand why it take longer than an hour...

Comment: @user1514042, well, OK, I have a better solution now, please see updated answer

Comment: See [Trick to Optimize TOP clause in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2053/trick-to-optimize-top-clause-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Some queries we run have t - 240:) thanks for the idea though