# Update 13 million rows - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, loops, cursor

How can I update `13 million` rows in stages by using a `cursor` or something?

Updating with the current script runs for days and still haven't finished.

There is a `row_id` field. `1 - 13m`

Only one field needs to be updated.

```
    UPDATE
        [CIPC].[dbo].[tbldirector]
    SET
        [CIPC].[dbo].[tbldirector].ENT_NUM = REG.Ent_Number
    FROM
        [CIPC].[dbo].[tbldirector] DIR
    INNER JOIN
        [Cipc].[dbo].[tblregister]  REG
    ON 
        DIR.ENT_LONGNAME = REG.ENT_NAME
```

Comment: you are loading the values from other table or can you tel me the sorce?

Comment: `Updating with the current script runs for days and still haven't finished.`. Why? Did you investigate the cause? 13M rows to update finish normally in seconds. Do proper due diligence and figure out why is your update so slow. Most likely it did not even start updating a single row and is blocked.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244360/how-to-update-2-new-columns-created-in-a-table-which-has-more-than-250-million-r/17244402#17244402).

Comment: Are the Name columns indexed? Is ENT_NAME unique within tblregister? Hopefully the answer is yes to both questions. If not then that may explain why your update takes so long.

Comment: I believe there is multiple occurrences of both.. For instance - 5 different people will be listed with same ent_name and ent_number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this case you don't need `cursor`. You can do it with a loop like this.

```
    DECLARE @indx int, @StepSize INT

SET @indx = 1
SET @StepSize = 100000

BEGIN TRAN 
    WHILE (EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM [CIPC].[dbo].[tbldirector] WHERE row_id >= @indx))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Going to update indx ' + REPLICATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @indx) + ' -- ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @indx + @StepSize) + ' | ', 200)
        UPDATE [CIPC].[dbo].[tbldirector]
            SET [CIPC].[dbo].[tbldirector].ENT_NUM = REG.Ent_Number
            FROM [CIPC].[dbo].[tbldirector] DIR
            INNER JOIN [Cipc].[dbo].[tblregister]  REG
                ON DIR.ENT_LONGNAME = REG.ENT_NAME
            WHERE row_id BETWEEN @indx AND @indx + @StepSize
        SELECT @indx = @indx + @StepSize
        SELECT REPLICATE(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @indx) + ' | ', 10), 200)
    END
COMMIT
```

Comment: This is incorrect as a crash/server shutdown inside the loop execution will leave it impossible to resume. You must persist the @indx and resume from it next iteration.

Comment: @RemusRusanu that a good point, I just provided a generic approach. to handle a crash/server shutdown / restart SQL Service, I wrapped it inside transaction

Comment: @Luis LL - Thank you kindly. Is there perhaps any way that I can print a progress?

Comment: well,... yes and no that I know, you could use `PRINT` but SSMS will print the information in the `Results` pane at it's own rate... sometimes I use a `quick & dirty fill the buffer`, something like the updated response

Answer (score 0):

This below link have three methods to do the needed,

http://ksadba.wordpress.com/2008/06/16/updating-millions-of-rows-merge-vs-bulk-collect/

Comment: the article title shows `Oracle`, does it apply for `SQL-Server` as well (I confess that I didn't read it